# If you log out, how can you make sure that the user who logs out does not produce nil uid when a different user registers?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

currently when user a logs out and b registers, the code detects b as not having a uid. To clarify further, uid refers to the user id given to each user in firebase. uid is used all over the code, but in this section it is also referred to as people.key.

```
@IBAction func outSignOutTapped(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
                KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")


                 do {
                          try Auth.auth().signOut()

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "one", sender: self)





                      } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                          print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
                      }



               }
```

Now for the uid part

```
  let thisUsersUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid //Mr. Dunn's uid
```

.......

```
  if people.key != thisUsersUid {

                    let userId = people.key
                    let coordSnap = people.childSnapshot(forPath: "Coordinates")
                    let lat = coordSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
                    let lon = coordSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude").value as! CLLocationDegrees
```

error at let lat:

```
 11:09:36 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa [Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0), Optional(0.0)]
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10b2cf040) to 'NSNumber' (0x10a39cd60).
2019-12-18 23:10:21.662183+0100 daylike[4548:97905] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10b2cf040) to 'NSNumber' (0x10a39cd60).
(lldb)
```

Error log:

```
ake a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-12-19 23:53:23.616220+0100 daylike[5022:112754] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e7660 smile.png.width == 1.6*smile.png.height   (active, names: smile.png:0x7fce84735ea0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e53b0 UIButton:0x7fce84736300'ViewLikes'.width == 2.78182*UIButton:0x7fce84736300'ViewLikes'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e7b10 smile.png.width == 0.32*UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.width   (active, names: smile.png:0x7fce84735ea0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e5c70 smile.png.height == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.height   (active, names: smile.png:0x7fce84735ea0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000081d5e0 UIButton:0x7fce84736300'ViewLikes'.height == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000081d6d0 UIButton:0x7fce84736300'ViewLikes'.width == 0.32*UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000080ed00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.width == 414   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e53b0 UIButton:0x7fce84736300'ViewLikes'.width == 2.78182*UIButton:0x7fce84736300'ViewLikes'.height   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2019-12-19 23:53:23.617771+0100 daylike[5022:112754] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e7660 smile.png.width == 1.6*smile.png.height   (active, names: smile.png:0x7fce84735ea0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e7b10 smile.png.width == 0.32*UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.width   (active, names: smile.png:0x7fce84735ea0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e5c70 smile.png.height == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.height   (active, names: smile.png:0x7fce84735ea0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000804af0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.height == 54.6667   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000080ed00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fce84740590.width == 414   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008e7660 smile.png.width == 1.6*smile.png.height   (active, names: smile.png:0x7fce84735ea0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
peoplekey 3WikAKJ6LKPyqVctTFmVGM6xR6n1
3WikAKJ6LKPyqVctTFmVGM6xR6n1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 466m0XHCOVSxQYrG5I5OmCPJJJt2
466m0XHCOVSxQYrG5I5OmCPJJJt2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 5PdErtXeg8f5hQ8cmcv5I1UqPTp1
5PdErtXeg8f5hQ8cmcv5I1UqPTp1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 5VbL3Adj7teM2KNJkF4GIexBJhE2
5VbL3Adj7teM2KNJkF4GIexBJhE2 coords: 37.3962622  -122.17851528
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 6NZlG4kiUuUAAWUlr7ollhTKxFE3
6NZlG4kiUuUAAWUlr7ollhTKxFE3 coords: 50.05484386295426  8.22686599248034
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 6nnvKAJnDVP9RwZkJlbqbAPdZRV2
6nnvKAJnDVP9RwZkJlbqbAPdZRV2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2
9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey CKGbzFGSPFderkpOfJfUVXvIwvC3
CKGbzFGSPFderkpOfJfUVXvIwvC3 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey CN0lXQQbVcXlI86IoJ1rGnMsxRj1
CN0lXQQbVcXlI86IoJ1rGnMsxRj1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey D6rTvyLS2uQYNuGgkvUT65vN3Hw1
D6rTvyLS2uQYNuGgkvUT65vN3Hw1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey K1eqsVZfKGgIf0sS1UZcPNxY62x1
K1eqsVZfKGgIf0sS1UZcPNxY62x1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey KBGuqWCEXZhFXR33l5axz6ai7a92
KBGuqWCEXZhFXR33l5axz6ai7a92 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey LSFcSfW6c1SnnMWPr4DLNqxyOW63
LSFcSfW6c1SnnMWPr4DLNqxyOW63 coords: 50.054755  8.226925570795801
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey LZ8aB0M3dMTD71Qjv5IRaFrTKwD2
LZ8aB0M3dMTD71Qjv5IRaFrTKwD2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey MDbCHVaszzQ0j86b5fmDvZoL2Ow1
MDbCHVaszzQ0j86b5fmDvZoL2Ow1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2
NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey PxaBTBPuFdhXFRDAtIwIvQ46FjH3
PxaBTBPuFdhXFRDAtIwIvQ46FjH3 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey QE8RdufiBzO252GP5MuYF0ntjzm2
QE8RdufiBzO252GP5MuYF0ntjzm2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey YrE847AEzcQp1DkpxcKLoZvQJWX2
YrE847AEzcQp1DkpxcKLoZvQJWX2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey cgDx4BgjN7Ph1uabfSsjlqo0tGC2
cgDx4BgjN7Ph1uabfSsjlqo0tGC2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey iQ6TcmQpsTQ9rzMfkrTARUCDBk23
iQ6TcmQpsTQ9rzMfkrTARUCDBk23 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey r1BFM3LxYwQr4O0hIyDieK1vlXp1
r1BFM3LxYwQr4O0hIyDieK1vlXp1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey s2I9l7FfYigTKdJ53LL1FBGM7dg1
s2I9l7FfYigTKdJ53LL1FBGM7dg1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey wCxOHbCZckRY7stkWmYz2A5dqIt1
wCxOHbCZckRY7stkWmYz2A5dqIt1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey wErp3lre8dSdWl5MMzSU9r9Xm8p2
wErp3lre8dSdWl5MMzSU9r9Xm8p2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey ySJEiAPcbZZGCpQIuSDtTvQmUvW2
ySJEiAPcbZZGCpQIuSDtTvQmUvW2 coords: 50.054651173253504  8.226782428878275
vulva <+0.00000000,+0.00000000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
1576795991862
2019-12-19 22:53:11 +0000
oooooooo
11
dick 2019-12-19 22:53:11 +0000
locations = 10.054755 4.226925
dict <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
locations = 10.054755 4.226925
dict <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:53:23 PM Central European Standard Time
good
good
locations = 10.054755 4.226925
locations = 10.054755 4.226925
2019-12-19 23:53:34.999558+0100 daylike[5022:112754] <UITableView: 0x7fce8807d400; frame = (0 0; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000024253b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002b00660>; contentOffset: {0, -88}; contentSize: {414, 812}; adjustedContentInset: {88, 0, 34, 0}>'s window is not equal to <daylike.ViewController: 0x7fce84744060>'s view's window!
2019-12-19 23:53:36.629333+0100 daylike[5022:112754] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2019-12-19 23:53:40.046726+0100 daylike[5022:113573] [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: NightSlight.daylike due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled
Optional(<FIRUser: 0x60000002c930>)
peoplekey 3WikAKJ6LKPyqVctTFmVGM6xR6n1
3WikAKJ6LKPyqVctTFmVGM6xR6n1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 466m0XHCOVSxQYrG5I5OmCPJJJt2
466m0XHCOVSxQYrG5I5OmCPJJJt2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 5PdErtXeg8f5hQ8cmcv5I1UqPTp1
5PdErtXeg8f5hQ8cmcv5I1UqPTp1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 5VbL3Adj7teM2KNJkF4GIexBJhE2
5VbL3Adj7teM2KNJkF4GIexBJhE2 coords: 37.3962622  -122.17851528
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 6NZlG4kiUuUAAWUlr7ollhTKxFE3
6NZlG4kiUuUAAWUlr7ollhTKxFE3 coords: 50.05484386295426  8.22686599248034
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 6nnvKAJnDVP9RwZkJlbqbAPdZRV2
6nnvKAJnDVP9RwZkJlbqbAPdZRV2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey 9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2
9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey CKGbzFGSPFderkpOfJfUVXvIwvC3
CKGbzFGSPFderkpOfJfUVXvIwvC3 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey CN0lXQQbVcXlI86IoJ1rGnMsxRj1
CN0lXQQbVcXlI86IoJ1rGnMsxRj1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey D6rTvyLS2uQYNuGgkvUT65vN3Hw1
D6rTvyLS2uQYNuGgkvUT65vN3Hw1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey K1eqsVZfKGgIf0sS1UZcPNxY62x1
K1eqsVZfKGgIf0sS1UZcPNxY62x1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey KBGuqWCEXZhFXR33l5axz6ai7a92
KBGuqWCEXZhFXR33l5axz6ai7a92 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey LSFcSfW6c1SnnMWPr4DLNqxyOW63
LSFcSfW6c1SnnMWPr4DLNqxyOW63 coords: 50.054755  8.226925570795801
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey LZ8aB0M3dMTD71Qjv5IRaFrTKwD2
LZ8aB0M3dMTD71Qjv5IRaFrTKwD2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey MDbCHVaszzQ0j86b5fmDvZoL2Ow1
MDbCHVaszzQ0j86b5fmDvZoL2Ow1 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2
NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey PxaBTBPuFdhXFRDAtIwIvQ46FjH3
PxaBTBPuFdhXFRDAtIwIvQ46FjH3 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey QE8RdufiBzO252GP5MuYF0ntjzm2
QE8RdufiBzO252GP5MuYF0ntjzm2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey YrE847AEzcQp1DkpxcKLoZvQJWX2
YrE847AEzcQp1DkpxcKLoZvQJWX2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey cgDx4BgjN7Ph1uabfSsjlqo0tGC2
cgDx4BgjN7Ph1uabfSsjlqo0tGC2 coords: 10.054755  4.226925
vulva <+10.05475500,+4.22692500> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/19/19, 11:52:48 PM Central European Standard Time
alphaaa
aaaaaaaa []
peoplekey ftT8j0ufb7Ylbz9gN2LvFuG5KCC3
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x109278040) to 'NSNumber' (0x108345d60).
2019-12-19 23:53:44.864035+0100 daylike[5022:112754] Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x109278040) to 'NSNumber' (0x108345d60).
(lldb)
```

Comment: It looks like coordSnap is null, not the UID. Can you confirm?

Comment: @DevKyle I though about that immidiately after posting. It does look like it from the error, but it doesn't make sense because all coordsnaps should be in firebase regardless of logout or not (for reference: registering works if you restart the app and don't try to register after logging out). So I am thinking: coordSnap finds coordinates for uids, and maybe if uid is not detected, it automatically can't find the coordSnap even though it exists.

Comment: Why don’t you print(UID) and comment out the coordSnap lines? Let me know what that says

Comment: @DevKyle I can't comment out the coordSnap lines because it causes error all over the app, but I did run it again with people.key printed. I am adding error log in the question.